# Adding contents list to the beginning of each chapter with minitoc

Tags: minitoc

I am trying to use the **minitoc** package to add contents to the beginning of each chapter. It dosen't seem to work, I have seen in the documentation that there might be problems when using starred chapters or

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}...
```

But whatever i try to include it dosen't seem to work... any suggestions ? maybe I am misplacing the **\dominitoc** or missing something here

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=green,urlcolor=red}

\usepackage{minitoc}

% --------------------------------------------- %

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{rom}       

\begin{titlepage}
Some text   
\end{titlepage}

\newpage\thispagestyle{plain} 
\addtocounter{rom}{1}\setcounter{page}{2}~
\newpage\thispagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{page}{3}

\chapter*{Declaration}
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}

\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\dominitoc
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
{
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
  \tableofcontents
}

\newpage\thispagestyle{plain}~
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}
\minitoc
\section{Motivation}
\newpage\cleardoublepage

\chapter{background}
\section{Motivation}
\newpage\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason adding **\adjustmtc** before the **\minitoc** solves the prolem.

The problem was arising after using **\addcontentsline** and so I solved the problem by adding just as many **\adjustmtc**. So for the code provided in my question, the solution would look like this:

```
...
\chapter{Introduction}
\adjustmtc\adjustmtc
\minitoc
\section{Motivation}
\newpage\cleardoublepage
...
```

Comment: Please extent your answer to something anybody can compile such other uses do not have to build a document around this fragment